Why the icon of floatingbutton in compose will not be change when some value changed
I have a compose function
@Composable
fun MediaPlayerController(
    isMediaPlaying: Boolean,
    onStart: () -> Unit,
    onNext: () -> Unit
) {
    Row() {
        FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = { onStart() },
        ) {
            Icon(imageVector = if (isMediaPlaying) Icons.Filled.Pause else Icons.Filled.PlayArrow, contentDescription = null)

        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun BottomBarPlayer(
    media: Media,
    isMediaPlaying: Boolean,
    onStart: () -> Unit,
    onNext: () -> Unit,
) {
    BottomAppBar(content = {
        Column(
        ) {
            Row(
            ) {
                MediaPlayerController(
                    isMediaPlaying = isMediaPlaying,
                    onStart = onStart,
                    onNext = onNext
                )
            }
        }
    })
}

@Composable
fun App(
    isMediaPlaying: Boolean,
    mediaList: MutableList<Media>,
    currentPlayingMedia: Media,
    onItemClicked: (Int) -> Unit,
) {
    Scaffold(        bottomBar = {
            BottomBarPlayer(media = currentPlayingMedia , isMediaPlaying =isMediaPlaying , onStart = onStart,onNext=onNext,navController=navController)
        }
    )

    }
}

    @Composable
    fun Main() {
        LMusicTheme {
            Surface(
            ) {
                App(
                    isMediaPlaying = viewModel.isPlaying,
                    currentPlayingMedia = viewModel.currentSelectedMedia,
                    onStart = {
                        viewModel.onUiEvents(UIEvents.PlayToggle)
                    },
            }
        }
    }

  fun onUiEvents(uiEvents: UIEvents) = viewModelScope.launch {
        when(uiEvents){
            UIEvents.SeekToNext ->mediaPlayerServiceHandle.onPlayerEvents(PlayerEvent.SeekToNext)
            is UIEvents.PlayToggle -> {
                mediaPlayerServiceHandle.onPlayerEvents(
                    PlayerEvent.PlayToggle
                )
            }
        }
    }

 suspend fun onPlayerEvents(
        playerEvent: PlayerEvent, selectedAudioIndex: Int = -1, seekPosition: Long = 0
    ) {
        when (playerEvent) {
            PlayerEvent.PlayToggle -> playToggle()
            PlayerEvent.SelectMediaChange -> {
                when (selectedAudioIndex) {
                    exoPlayer.currentMediaItemIndex -> {
                        if (exoPlayer.isPlaying){
                            _mediaState.value = MediaState.Playing(
                                isPlaying = false
                            )
                            playToggle()
                        }else{
                            _mediaState.value = MediaState.Playing(
                                isPlaying = true
                            )
                            playToggle()
                        }
                    }

                    else -> {
                  exoPlayer.seekToDefaultPosition(selectedAudioIndex)
                        _mediaState.value = MediaState.Playing(
                            isPlaying = true
                        )
                        exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
                        startProgressUpdate()
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }

  private suspend fun playToggle() {
        if (exoPlayer.isPlaying) {
            exoPlayer.pause()
            _mediaState.value = MediaState.CurrentPlaying(
                exoPlayer.currentMediaItemIndex
            )
            _mediaState.value = MediaState.Playing(
                isPlaying = false
            )        } else {
            _mediaState.value = MediaState.Playing(
                isPlaying = true
            )
            exoPlayer.play()
            _mediaState.value = MediaState.CurrentPlaying(
                exoPlayer.currentMediaItemIndex
            )
        }
    }

In MediaViewModel
    var isPlaying by savedStateHandle.saveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    private val _uiState: MutableStateFlow<UIState> = MutableStateFlow(UIState.Initial)
    val uiState: StateFlow<UIState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

In MediaServiceHandle
sealed class MediaState {
    object Initial : MediaState()
    data class Ready(val duration: Long) : MediaState()
    data class Progress(val progress: Long) : MediaState()
    data class Buffering(val progress: Long) : MediaState()
    data class Playing(val isPlaying: Boolean) : MediaState()
    data class CurrentPlaying(val mediaItemIndex: Int) : MediaState()
}

I don't know why i click that floatbuttom,its icon not change ,although isPlaying were changed
i don't know how let it changed,i am a nood ,please help me ,thanks
i can't post more code,i try delete some code that seems not useful for this question,if need ,i will post,sorry i am noob
to be honest ,i want to try use currentRecomposeScope.invalidate() but i think it not good,have other ways?

Please edit your post and also show how you declared your isPlaying variable in your ViewModel.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@lin Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, please mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of the answer.

In order to update smth according to data in compose function (such as your Icon in MediaPlayerController) you want to remember your data as mutableStateOf. Smth like:
@Composable
fun MediaPlayerController(
    isMediaPlaying: Boolean,
    onStart: () -> Unit,
    onNext: () -> Unit
) {
    var isMediaPlayingState by remember{
        mutableStateOf(isMediaPlaying)
    }
    Row() {
        FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = { 
                onStart() 
                isMediaPlayingState = isMediaPlayingState.not() },
        ) {
            Icon(imageVector = if (isMediaPlayingState) Icons.Filled.Pause else Icons.Filled.PlayArrow, contentDescription = null)

        }
    }
}

This way as soon as isMediaPlayingState changes its value, Compose will automatically redraw all the compose functions, that depend on new value (Icon in your case). The same concept applies everywhere.

Although that is not wrong it doesn't address the fact that there is already such a variable in the viewmodel, see also BenjyTec's comment on the question. Perhaps that variable is already a mutable state, mabye it is a flow (which would be preferable), it may be a LiveData or something entirely different, but we actually don't know until the op updates their question accordingly. Until then any attempts to answer are mere speculation. In short, you shouldn't answer a question that is lacking vital information. That said: Welcome to Stack Overflow. :)

I update my code ,thanks,to be honest,it used mutableStateOf

When we trace back the isMediaPlaying variable from your FloatingActionButton, we can find that it is set from the ViewModel:
var isPlaying by savedStateHandle.saveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

However, it seems that you never modify the value of the isPlaying ViewModel variable (or at least not in the code that you showed us).  The only thing you are doing is that you create some updated MediaState.Playing objects, but you never actually update the isPlaying variable from the ViewModel itself.
// this updates mediaState, but not the isPlaying variable of ViewModel
_mediaState.value = MediaState.Playing(
    isPlaying = true
)

Please try to also change the isPlaying variable accordingly when you toggle:
private suspend fun playToggle() {
    if (exoPlayer.isPlaying) {
        exoPlayer.pause()
        isPlaying = false
        //...
    } else {
        //...
        exoPlayer.play()
        isPlaying = true
        //...
    }
}

Note that there are some untypical things in your code, you sometimes write a value to the _mediaState and immediately overwrite it.
_mediaState.value = MediaState.CurrentPlaying(
    exoPlayer.currentMediaItemIndex
)
_mediaState.value = MediaState.Playing(
    isPlaying = false
)

I don't know if that is intended, you might want to take a look at the MutableStateFlow documentation.

thanks,i have another question,could i delete isPlaying inViewModel and use isPlaying inMediaState.Playing(),what should i changed it ,thanks you

I want to let isPlaying in viewmodel is following isPlaying inMediaState.Playing(),what i should change ,thanks
